# Proof that $ -1 = \infty $ .  

Tags: infinity, fake-proofs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Infinity = -1 paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/infinity-1-paradox)

$1+2+4+8+16+\ldots = \infty$

$LHS=1(1+2+4+8+16+\dots)$

$LHS=(2-1)(1+2+4+8+16+\ldots)$

$LHS=(2+4+8+16+32+\ldots)-(1+2+4+8+16+\ldots)$

$LHS=2+4+8+16+32+\ldots-1-2-4-8-16-\ldots$

$LHS=-1$

$\therefore \space -1 = \infty$

what

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Math.SE! Your question has actually been asked before, in a slightly different form; see the linked question above. That doesn't mean there's anything wrong with your question, just that we don't want to have duplicates.