# Is $\sum \limits_{n=0}^{\infty}2^n=-1$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, divergent-series

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Infinity = -1 paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/infinity-1-paradox)

[MinutePhysics](http://youtu.be/kIq5CZlg8Rg) has what initially looks like a divergent series summing to -1. The youtube comments are... lacking in clarity. The argument MinutePhysics loosely makes is

$1+2+4+8+16...$

$=(1)(1+2+4+8+16...)$

$=(2-1)(1+2+4+8+16...)$

$=(2+4+8+16+32...) - (1+2+4+8+16...)$

$=-1 + (2+4+8+16+32...)-(2+4+8+16...)$

Is this proof correct, and if not, what is the error?

Comment: the extension of $\sum z^n$ to the rest of the plane is $1/(1-z)$ which is $-1$ at $z=2$

Comment: Manipulated series must be convergent to render the arithmetic sensible.

Comment: @yoyo, what do you mean by the extension of $\sum z^n$?

Comment: @David: he meant "analytic continuation". You do have what's called a "geometric series"...

Comment: @percusse: This series is convergent in the $2$-adic metric and indeed converges to $-1$.

Comment: @ZhenLin Yep, but I didn't want to complicate things. That's why I didn't write *the series are not convergent*.

Comment: Hmmmm... Im going to have to learn the p-adic system. All I know is that the geometric series diverges, therefore playing with the arithmetic is bound to create paradoxes.