# Evaluating an infinite series.

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find $$1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots$$

Now I let $$s = 1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + \cdots$$
So,
$$s = 1 + 2(1 + 2 + 4 + \cdots)$$
$$s = 1 + 2s$$
and this gives us:
$$s = -1$$

Is there a more rigorous proof for this bizarre result or is this completely incorrect?

Comment: Before calculating the sum of an infinte series, you have to SHOW that the series converge.

Comment: Right. I get it now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [$1 + 2 + 4 + 8 + 16 \ldots = -1$ paradox](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37327/1-2-4-8-16-ldots-1-paradox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've shown that if the series converges to a finite value, that value is $-1$. Whether it converges [depends on the norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ostrowski%27s_theorem) applied to the error terms $\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}2^j-(-1)=2^n$. If we use the Euclidean norm, the trivial norm, or the $p$-adic norm with $p\ne2$, the series diverges; [if we use](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XFDM1ip5HdU) the $2$-adic norm, the series converges to $-1$ as claimed.